# How to filter with multiple values in the same field mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a field named `shoe_subtype_id` which is passing 2 or more `id` from the front end, I need to get all shoes related to both `shoe_subtype_id`. I have used `"$in"` operator but didn't get the shoes related to both `id`, only getting the shoe details of any one of the `id`.

The input given is:

```json
{listing_type:For Sale},
{shoe_subtype_id:103,105},
{district:calicut}...
```

The expected output is:

```json
{"brand":"puma",
"year":"2020",
shoe_subtype_id:103,
...},
{"brand":"puma",
"year":"2021",
shoe_subtype_id:105,
...},
{"brand":"nike",
"year":"2020",
shoe_subtype_id:105,
...},
```

The query given is:

```js
        if (property_sub_type2_id) {
      search.property_sub_type2_id=({$in:property_sub_type2_id.split(",")})
}
```

**please help**

Comment: use [$all](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)?

Comment: No matching results @1sina1

Comment: please add some sample Json input and your expected output

Comment: Please elaborate more

Comment: @AkshayA Can you post the whole query and filter construction code?